# Make table fit on screen? (JQueryMobile/Cordova)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

My javascript function basically creates a dynamic page and displays the data fetched from the database, however when the data is displayed it overflows past the mobile screen width.

Can someone tell me what I can use to ensure that table fits within the screen or if there is another way I can go about fitting my data in.

JavaScript table:

```
var formElements = "<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Location</th><th>NoPeople</th><th>Date</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
 for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
formElements += "<tr><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Title + "</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Location +"</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).NoPeople + "</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Date +"</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Description + "</td></tr>";
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQM's data-role table attribute: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_tables.asp)

```
var formElements = "<table id='yourTableID' data-role='table' data-mode='reflow' class='ui-responsive table-stroke table-stripe'><thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Location</th><th>NoPeople</th><th>Date</th><th>Description</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
 for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
    formElements += "<tr><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Title + "</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Location +"</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).NoPeople + "</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Date +"</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).Description + "</td></tr>";
 }

 formElements+="</tbody></table>";
```

And after adding the table to the DOM refresh it:

```
$("#yourTableID").table("refresh");
```

You could take a look also to [Responsive Tables](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables).

Comment: Didn't use the table refresh though, as when I had that in, it prevented the screen from scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't set a table width? By setting it to 95% you reduce the chance of having a scroll bar.

```
<table width="95%">
```